# Cloud9 Warning do I just ignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, cloud9

During testing in chapter 3 I get the following warning, is this ok to ignore?

> RubyDep: WARNING: your Ruby is outdated/buggy. Please upgrade. (To disable >warnings, set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
>   Run options: --seed 18589

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: check ruby version, Install RVM and add ruby version to your gem file.

Comment: Hi I'm using Cloud9 IDE , ruby version 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.2

Answer (score 3):

I'd say **yes**, it's okay.

...**for as long as you're following a tutorial** that was staged on specific versions of Ruby, Rails and other libraries. What's told in the tutorial was likely tested on these and works even despite the software being "outdated/buggy".

Depending on how ready you are to resolve sudden issues and deal with changes as the result of upgrading anything...

- You can either go for using latest versions ***now*** and *expect the outcomes to diverge* from what's given in the tutorial...
- ...or *strictly follow the tutorial* and *use outdated versions* **until the tutorial is complete** and there are no more directions and expectations.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to above answers I'd suggest you to update the Ruby to latest version because I had same error when I revisited sample app and without updating I was not able to run tests. So just follow these simple steps and update Ruby to latest version:

As stated by Mo H., install [RVM](https://rvm.io/) first.

and the [upgrade](https://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading) it to 2.3.1.

Also after upgrading, make sure to check the ruby version using `ruby -v` and if it still shows **ruby-2.3.0** then run

```
rvm use default ruby-2.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really dependent on what version of ruby you are running. In general it might be fine to ignore it, but if I were you I wouldn't risk it. Your best bet is to install [RVM](https://rvm.io/). This will allow you switch between ruby versions, so you can swap to a newer version of ruby and make sure everything works as it should and see if the warning goes away.

Warnings are there for a reason, and while you can ignore them, it can come back to haunt you later. When its something simple like this its better to just deal with it.